# Modeling associations between ActiveRecord objects with Redis: avoiding multiple queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nosql, foreign-keys, redis, relationship

I've been reading / playing around with the idea of using Redis to complement my ActiveRecord models, in particular as a way of modeling relationships. Also watched a few screencasts like this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dH6VYRMRQFw

It seems like a good idea in cases where you want to fetch one object at a time, but it seems like the approach breaks down when you need to show a list of objects along with each of their associations (e.g. in a View or in a JSON response in the case of an API).

Whereas in the case of using purely ActiveRecord, you can use `includes` and eager loading to avoid running N more queries, I can't seem to think of how to do so when depending purely on Redis to model relationships.

For instance, suppose you have the following (taken from the very helpful [redis_on_rails](https://github.com/obie/redis_on_rails) project):

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base

  def attendees
    # Attendee.find(rdb[:attendee_ids])
    Attendee.find_all_by_id(rdb[:attendee_ids].smembers)
  end

  def register(attendee)  
    Redis.current.multi do
      rdb[:attendee_ids].sadd(attendee.id)
      attendee.rdb[:conference_ids].sadd id
    end
  end

  def unregister(attendee)
    Redis.current.multi do
      rdb[:attendee_ids].srem(attendee.id)
      attendee.rdb[:conference_ids].srem id
    end
  end

end
```

If I did something like

```
conferences = Conference.first(20)
conferences.each {|c|
    c.attendees.each {|a| puts a.name}
}
```

I'm simply getting the first 20 conferences and getting the attendees in each and printing them out, but you can imagine a case where I am rendering the conferences along with a list of the attendees in a list in a view. In the above case, I would be running into the classic N+1 query problem.

If I had modeled the relationship in SQL along with `has_many`, I would have been able to use the `includes` function to avoid the same problem.

Ideas, links, questions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis can provide major benefits to your application's infrastructure, but I've found that, due to the specific operations you can perform on the various data types, you really need to put some thought ahead of time into how you're going to access your data. In this example, if you are very often iterating over a bunch of conferences and outputting the attendees, and are not otherwise benefiting from Redis' ability to do rich set operations (such as intersections, unions, etc.), maybe it's not a good fit for that data model.

On the other hand, if you *are* benefiting from Redis in performance-intensive parts of your application, it may be worth eating the occasional N+1 GET on Redis in order to reap those benefits. You have to do profiling on the parts of the app that you care about to see if the tradeoffs are worth it.

You may also be able to structure your data in Redis/your application in such a way that you can avoid the N+1 GETs; for example, if you can get all the keys up front, you can use [MGET](http://redis.io/commands/mget) to get all the keys at once, which is a fast O(N) operation, or use [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to avoid network latency for multiple lookups.

In an application I work on, we've built a caching layer that caches the foreign key IDs for has_many relationships so that we can do fast lookups on cached versions of a large set of models that have complex relationships with each other; while fetching these by SQL, we generate very large, relatively slow SQL queries, but by using Redis and the cached foreign keys, we can do a few MGETs without hitting the database at all. However, we only arrived at that solution by investigating where our bottlenecks were and discussing how we might avoid them.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer and for pointing me to MGET; I think in this example, there is a way to run a map over all my conferences to grab all the relevant attendee ids and fetch them all using a SELECT IN statement, in effect doing my own eager loading ahead of time.